# BTYD package. error in bgnbd plotting: need finite 'ylim' values for frequency in calibration

Tags: r, plot

I'm having some trouble when plotting the "bgnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration" in the "BTYD" package.
There is no NA in the dataset and other plots works without error.
Below is my code for the plots:

```
CustData<- read.csv("~/ltv/CustData")
> cal.cbs<-cbind(CustData$t.x,CustData$x,CustData$T.cal,CustData$x.star)
> colnames(cal.cbs)<-c("t.x","x","T.cal","x.star")
est.params<-c(0.0313,0.9165,1.088,0.7903)
bgnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration(est.params,cal.cbs,7)
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Kara
[subset of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkIXD.png)

Comment: hi, did you find a solution to your problem? I bumped into the same issue and also would appreciate some helpful suggestions :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I am stuck with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed for pnbd.pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration. Repeat the same for bgnbd. If you look at the actual function for pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration :
"https://github.com/cran/BTYD/blob/master/R/pnbd.R" (check here)

```
pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration <- function(params, cal.cbs, censor, plotZero = TRUE, 
                                            xlab = "Calibration period transactions", ylab = "Customers", title = "Frequency of Repeat Transactions") {

  tryCatch(x <- cal.cbs[, "x"], error = function(e) stop("Error in pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration: cal.cbs must have a frequency column labelled \"x\""))
  tryCatch(T.cal <- cal.cbs[, "T.cal"], error = function(e) stop("Error in pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration: cal.cbs must have a column for length of time observed labelled \"T.cal\""))

  dc.check.model.params(c("r", "alpha", "s", "beta"), params, "pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration")
  if (censor > max(x)) 
    stop("censor too big (> max freq) in PlotFrequencyInCalibration.")

  n.x <- rep(0, max(x) + 1)
  custs = nrow(cal.cbs)

  for (ii in unique(x)) {
    n.x[ii + 1] <- sum(ii == x)
  }

  n.x.censor <- sum(n.x[(censor + 1):length(n.x)])
  n.x.actual <- c(n.x[1:censor], n.x.censor)

  T.value.counts <- table(T.cal)
  T.values <- as.numeric(names(T.value.counts))
  n.T.values <- length(T.values)

  total.probability <- 0

  n.x.expected <- rep(0, length(n.x.actual))

  for (ii in 1:(censor)) {
    this.x.expected <- 0
    for (T.idx in 1:n.T.values) {
      T <- T.values[T.idx]
      if (T == 0) 
        next
      n.T <- T.value.counts[T.idx]
      expected.given.x.and.T <- n.T * pnbd.pmf(params, T, ii - 1)
      this.x.expected <- this.x.expected + expected.given.x.and.T
      total.probability <- total.probability + expected.given.x.and.T/custs
    }
    n.x.expected[ii] <- this.x.expected
  }
  n.x.expected[censor + 1] <- custs * (1 - total.probability)

  col.names <- paste(rep("freq", length(censor + 1)), (0:censor), sep = ".")
  col.names[censor + 1] <- paste(col.names[censor + 1], "+", sep = "")
  censored.freq.comparison <- rbind(n.x.actual, n.x.expected)
  colnames(censored.freq.comparison) <- col.names

  cfc.plot <- censored.freq.comparison
  if (plotZero == FALSE) 
    cfc.plot <- cfc.plot[, -1]

  n.ticks <- ncol(cfc.plot)
  if (plotZero == TRUE) {
    x.labels <- 0:(n.ticks - 1)
    x.labels[n.ticks] <- paste(n.ticks - 1, "+", sep = "")
  } else {
    x.labels <- 1:(n.ticks)
    x.labels[n.ticks] <- paste(n.ticks, "+", sep = "")
  }

  ylim <- c(0, ceiling(max(cfc.plot,na.rm = TRUE) * 1.1))
  barplot(cfc.plot, names.arg = x.labels, beside = TRUE, ylim = ylim, main = title, 
          xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, col = 1:2)

  legend("topright", legend = c("Actual", "Model"), col = 1:2, lwd = 2)

  return(censored.freq.comparison)
}
```

There is a line:

```
ylim <- c(0, ceiling(max(cfc.plot) * 1.1))
```

Add to it, na.rm=TRUE

```
ylim <- c(0, ceiling(max(cfc.plot,na.rm = TRUE) * 1.1))
```

Run the function again, should work now